# Dummy data with Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, dummy-data

How can I set up dummy data with FactoryGirl?

Is there a way to set up dummy data with a factory in my integrated development environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I write a seed scribt to solve my problem:

in /db/seed.rb i implemented factory_girl and use a csv file to define custom datas.

seed.rb:

```
require 'factory_girl'
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join("datas.csv"), headers: true) do |row|
  post = FactoryGirl.create(:post) do |post|
    post.text = row[0]
  end
end
```

If you want to associate models with your test datas you can use FactoryGirl to create associated objects:

```
CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join("post_comments.csv"), headers: true) do |row|
  Post.all.each do |post|
    FactoryGirl.create(:comment, post: post) do |comment|
      comment.name = row[0]
    end
  end
end
```

You can also use the first CSV scribt and implement an factory wich create comments for each post.

> FactoryGirl.create(:post_with_comments)

Now you can use FactoryGirl to create x records for testing datas with csv.

Comment: could you share more details on your technique.  I have a CSV of test cases (inputs and outputs) I would like to use through FactoryGirl.